# In laravel 8How to Logout User after 15 min if user is inactive(do nothing)

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8 AUTH package. Once user is login and if he idle for 15 min. then auto logout user and redirect to main website page.
or how to write corn job for it for I am doing corn job like below in 15Update.php corn script
but nothing happen.

Comment: why using cronjob for it? you can use laravel sessions to logout.

Comment: you have to first log your activity and you have to check if your last activity time is >15 min from your current time then you have to restore your session.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the lifetime in the `config/session.php` file to 15 min.

If you want to accurate time with idle time, you must handle it via the log table in the database.

If you want to handle it via package and middleware, please read [this](https://medium.com/@julio.motol89/laravel-how-to-log-out-a-user-after-a-time-of-inactivity-99594dd73459) article.